# Java request through proxy with credentials

Tags: java, http, proxy, client, credentials

I can't get any Java implementation to make http request through proxy with credentials.

Now I'm compelled to use bash script `curl --proxy-user username:password ...`. Is there way to do the same in Java?

***UPD*** : ***since my proxy connection authentication is optional, I have to make proxy to use credentials*** like in curl example

Answer (score 3):

If you are using java 6 or higher , you can use the Proxy class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html

A sample usage will look like below

```
HttpURLConnection conn;
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("www.proxyserver.com", YOUR_PROXY_PORT));

URL httpUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) httpUrl.openConnection(proxy);
```

TO authenticate your your access 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

public  class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {


    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        String username = "yourUserName";
        String password = "YourPassword";
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());

    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for response. It does not look clear, is it possible to do it without global settings? Would be great to have it for rest-easy client

Comment: Yeah totally, but I don't see any global settings in my snippet . Can you be more specific?
Instead of "www.proxyserver.com" use your own proxy server setting,
and instead of "YOUR_PROXY_PORT" use your own value, most likely it will be 8080
Rest everything seems totally ok.
on a side note: proxy server is picked up from internet explorer settings or chrome settings

Comment: I mean that Authenticator is used by each connection, is not it?

Comment: If all your http requests require authentication then indeed Authenticator will be used by all connections, that's the way it is even using normal proxy servers. But that should not stop you from any kind of use case.

Comment: Shame on me, I didn't say that my proxy authentication is optional, but I need to make my connection use proxy with credentials. Authenticator use it only if connection require it, right?

Answer (score 1):

After much doing the surfing, I got this answer which perfectly suits my ask

Create the Rest Client Base class so that this can be applicable for all the rest Template calls

public class RestClientBase {
private RestTemplate restTemplate = null;

```
protected RestTemplate getTemplate() {
    string username = "username";
    String Password = "password";

    if (restTemplate == null) {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpReq = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("Proxy URL", PROXY_PORT)); // PROXY PORT needs to be integer
        clientHttpReq.setProxy(proxy);

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpReq);
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(username, Password));
    }

    return restTemplate;
}
```

}

Now Inherit this class in your actual rest client class where you are calling another API endpoint

public class ActualClientClass extends RestClientBase {

```
public String invokeActualService(String restAPINeedingUserNamePwdURL, class.String) {

    String result = getTemplate().getForObject(restAPINeedingUserNamePwdURL, String.class);

}
```

}

Just to highlight, this is exactly doing the same task as curl --proxy-user username:password